# Updating from StyleCop 4.7 (Classic) to StyleCop.Analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, code-organization, stylecop

I am upgrading stylecop classic to the latest version (StyleCop.Analyzers 1.0.0) in my VS2015 and based on the introductions from GitHub, I cannot use Settings.StyleCop anymore but to create a new stylecop.json file.

Now the question is I do have some custom settigns inside the settings.StyleCop like "recognized words" in Spelling tab, and certain options inside Options Tab. How do I add them in the json file? Couldn't find anything on their github site about this. Please help.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the [schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json) that corresponds to the spelling tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All config options are documented here: [Configuration.md](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md)

The analyzers project removed spell checking in favor of performance [(see Issue 1057)](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1057)

> Several documentation rules are subjective and aim to establish the
>   quality of documentation content. These rules take CPU time to
>   evaluate and are an overall poor indicator of documentation quality. I
>   believe with the rules in place, developers will be focused on the
>   wrong aspects of documentation during the development process.
>
> ```
> SA1628: Documentation text must begin with a capital letter
> SA1630: Documentation text must contain whitespace
> SA1631: Documentation must meet character percentage
> SA1632: Documentation text must meet minimum character length
> SA1650: Element documentation must be spelled correctly
> ```
>
> I propose that each of these rules be permanently disabled in StyleCopAnalyzers.

Regarding spell checking,

You might consider using Code Analysis + [Code Analysis Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx).  (EX: [CA1704: Identifiers should be spelled correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264492.aspx))

Another option would be to use a visual studio plugin centered around spelling (see [Visual Studio Spell Checker Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a23de100-31a1-405c-b4b7-d6be40c3dfff))

Comment: Thank you. I actually got the response from the author in Github, but I didn't know about the "dictionary". your response has more detail that I can really use for. Thanks!!